# Excel C#: Testing if named range exists without risking an exception

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, exception

I want to check if a named `Range` exists in the current `Workbook` using an `Excel C# Add-In`.

The following code is working fine but causes an exception when the named range does not exist:

```
private static Excel.Workbook GetWorkbook()
{
    return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
}

public static bool DoesRangeExist(string rangeName)
{
    var workbook = GetWorkbook();
    var names = workbook.Names;

    try
    {
        names.Item(rangeName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

While debugging in `Visual Studio`, the code stops at the exception and prompts me to continue even though the exception is handled "properly":

[image]

I don't want to disable breaking on this type of exception since it could hide problems elsewhere. Therefore, it seems like using exceptions like above is bad practise in `C#`. How would you rewrite this without the use of exceptions? I tried iterating over the `names` collection and comparing each `name` element `ToString()` to the `rangeName` parameter but those comparisons don't return the expected result (an existing named range would e.g. return `false` instead of `true`). Besides this, I don't see any helpful methods `names` would provide to do a simple check if the item exists.

Comment: Can you clarify what type is `workbook.Names` ?

Comment: @Nkosi https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.names.aspx

Comment: the image litrally shows you have it set to break on that type of exception. So just... disable that? Also consider catching exactly that `TargetInvocationException` so other exceptions that may occur accidentally don't get caught by your lazy catch-all there.

Comment: Loop through all names in Workbook.Names. If your name is found return true. If you reach the end of the loop without finding it, return false.